# Ordenar una List de fechas en formato String en Java

Tags: java, lista, ordenamiento

Tengo una lista con unos valores de tipo string que representan fechas. Estoy tratando de realizar una función que me mandandole una lista desordenada me devuelva una lista con esos valores ordenados.

```
public class ValObj {

    private String time = "";
    private  String msg = "";

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

   public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
   }
}
```

---

```
    final List<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();
    dates.add("2020-01-08T11:38:48.826Z");
    dates.add("2020-01-08T11:38:55.826Z");
    dates.add("2020-01-08T11:38:51.826Z");
    dates.add("2020-01-08T11:38:42.826Z");
    dates.add("2020-01-08T11:38:46.826Z");
    dates.add("2020-01-08T11:38:49.826Z");
    dates.add("2020-01-08T11:38:38.826Z");
    dates.add("2020-01-08T11:38:41.826Z");
    dates.add("2020-01-08T11:38:30.826Z");

    final List<ValObj> objList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < dates.size(); i++) {
        final ValObj aux = new ValObj();
        aux.setMsg(dates.get(i));
        aux.setMsg(String.valueOf(i));
        objList.add(aux);
    }

    //Obtener la objList ordenada en base a los valores de fechas que estan en formato string
```

¿Alguna idea? Gracias de antemano

Comment: Y que has intentado o que te falla?

Comment: He intentado comparar las fechas directamente mediante String pero creo que es mejor pasarlo a Date para asegurar que la cadena corresponde con una fecha. El tema es que por ejemplo no doy con el formato para hacer el parseo. Y luego entiendo que hacer la transformación de tipos ralentiza el proceso. Pero puedo llegar a creer que estoy dándole mucha importancia e igual basta con hacer la comparación de cadenas. Al no saber cual manera es la optima preguntaba por si alguien podía facilitarme una solución y por que en su opinión es más optima frente a la otra.

Comment: Para ordenarlo puedes usar un `Collections.sort(dates);` o implementar tu propio `Comparator`  si quieres ordenarlo con algún criterio propio ya depende si quieres la funcion o hacerlo a mano

Comment: cuantas fechas a comparar? 15? 150? miles? millones? si la respuesta no es millones, estas tratando de solucionar un problema que no tenes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mí me gusta trabajar con las nuevas apis de Java 8 en lo posible así que vamos por pasos. Primero una función que mapee tus strings al tipo [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), que pertenece al paquete `java.time` estrenado en Java 8 y facilita mucho el trabajar con fechas:

```
private LocalDateTime formatToInstant(String timeInString) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.nnn'Z'");
    return LocalDateTime.parse(timeInString, formatter);
}
```

Y lo mismo para convertirla de vuelta:

```
private String formatToString(LocalDateTime time) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.nnn'Z'");
    return formatter.format(time);
}
```

Fíjate que el patrón es el mismo, por lo que podrías tenerlo como constante incluso. Además lo he hecho todo en una misma clase, pero tú podrías dividirlo si quieres.

Y ahora usando la api de streams:

```
List<String> sortedDates = dates.stream()
            .map(this::formatToInstant)     // Las mapeamos a LocalDateTime
            .sorted()                       // Las ordenamos según su orden natural
            .map(this::formatToString)      // Las convertimos de vuelta a String
            .collect(Collectors.toList());  // Creamos una nueva lista con las String ya ordenadas
```

Answer (score 1):

Bueno en este caso veo que podrias hacer ordenando la lista antes de recorrer tu for en donde les haces un set a tus objetos siendo tu código como bien menciona *@Cap.Teach* simplemente aumentanco un `Collections.sort(dates)`:

```
final ArrayList<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();
dates.add("2020-01-08T11:38:48.826Z");
dates.add("2020-01-08T11:38:55.826Z");
dates.add("2020-01-08T11:38:51.826Z");
dates.add("2020-01-08T11:38:42.826Z");
dates.add("2020-01-08T11:38:46.826Z");
dates.add("2020-01-08T11:38:49.826Z");
dates.add("2020-01-08T11:38:38.826Z");
dates.add("2020-01-08T11:38:41.826Z");
dates.add("2020-01-08T11:38:30.826Z");

final ArrayList<ValObj> objList = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.sort(dates); // Con esta linea ordenamos la lista

for (int i = 0; i < dates.size(); i++) {
    final ValObj aux = new ValObj();
    aux.setTime(dates.get(i)); // Aqui imagino que quisiste poner setTime y no setMsg
    aux.setMsg(String.valueOf(i));
    objList.add(aux);
}
System.out.println(dates.toString());
```

Y la otra seria ordenarlo *despues de que ya hiciste los set*, tambien utilizando el sort pero con algunos cambios. Te dejare un link para que revises sobre ésta forma de ordenar con objetos al final. De esta forma tu código quedaría de la siguiente así:

```
final ArrayList<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();
dates.add("2020-01-08T11:38:48.826Z");
dates.add("2020-01-08T11:38:55.826Z");
dates.add("2020-01-08T11:38:51.826Z");
dates.add("2020-01-08T11:38:42.826Z");
dates.add("2020-01-08T11:38:46.826Z");
dates.add("2020-01-08T11:38:49.826Z");
dates.add("2020-01-08T11:38:38.826Z");
dates.add("2020-01-08T11:38:41.826Z");
dates.add("2020-01-08T11:38:30.826Z");

final ArrayList<ValObj> objList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < dates.size(); i++) {
    final ValObj aux = new ValObj();
    aux.setTime(dates.get(i)); // Aqui imagino que quisiste poner setTime y no setMsg
    aux.setMsg(String.valueOf(i));
    objList.add(aux);
}

Collections.sort(objList, (Object o1, Object o2) -> {
    ValObj obj1 = (ValObj)o1;
    ValObj obj2 = (ValObj)o2;
    SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date date1 = null, date2 = null;
    try {
        // Convertimos las cadenas en date
        date1 = (Date)isoFormat.parse(obj1.getTime());
        date2 = (Date)isoFormat.parse(obj2.getTime());
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Stackoverflow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return date1.compareTo(date2); // Comparamos las fechas
});

// Mostramos la lista ordenada
for (ValObj persona : objList) {
    System.out.println(persona.getTime());
}
```

El resultado de la lista ordenada sería:

> ```
> 2020-01-08T11:38:30.826Z
> 2020-01-08T11:38:38.826Z
> 2020-01-08T11:38:41.826Z
> 2020-01-08T11:38:42.826Z
> 2020-01-08T11:38:46.826Z
> 2020-01-08T11:38:48.826Z
> 2020-01-08T11:38:49.826Z
> 2020-01-08T11:38:51.826Z
> 2020-01-08T11:38:55.826Z
> ```

Espero te sirva, puedes revisar [éste enlace](https://jarroba.com/ordenar-un-arraylist-en-java/) para ver ejemplos muy claros de como realizar ordenamientos con listas. Saludos ;)